# Using one button to play 2 sounds?

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Hi I've tried some ways to play 2 of my sound files using a random generator to an array an I even posted here twice but the errors I got persisted even with all that help. I am just askin if someone can code in.   Xcode 2 sounds files in which one of the 2 will play on the fist click an the other will play on the second click an it would alternate like that as the person keeps clicking the buttons ,   Reason I didn't code any for this topic was it seems whatever advice I get when implemented into Xcode always has some problem with what I already there so I will start fresh. I am using avaudio framework an playin mp3 files. Ty

Answer (score 0):

put this code into your IBAction of the button

```
if(flag == 0)
{
    // play file 1
    flag = 1;
}
else if(flag == 1)
{
    //play file 2
    flag = 0;
}
```

make flag as int variable @interface.

Comment: Or replace all of that code with: `flag = 1 - flag;`. That will toggle between 0 and 1.